# Create an html page, add 2 text boxes in which the user will input 2 numbers: n and m

Tags: javascript, html

In the HTML below, I have two text inputs to populate values of `n & m`. Both variables should hold integer numbers. `n` can be bigger or less than `m`. I want the summation of all even integer numbers between n and m on `Add` click button. The result will be displayed in an alert.

Below is my current code but it does not work.

Expected result for n = 4, m = 8 result should be 18. and n = 8, m = 4 result should be 18

```js
function Sum() {
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
  var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
  var s = 0;
  var i;
  if (n < m) {
    i = n;
    while (i <= m) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) s = s + i;
      i++;
      alert(s);
    }
  } else if (n > m) {
    i = m;
    while (i <= n) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) s = s + i;
      i++;
      alert(s);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Enter first number:
<input type="text" id="n" />
<br/> Enter second number:
<input type="text" id="m" />
<br/>
<button onclick="Sum()">Sum</button>
```

Comment: that doesn't work cause you placed the alert inside the loop. you shoud move it outside. also, like the answer from @andam, you dont need 2 different loops, just use [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano Thanks for the edit of my answer. You are correct. It should only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop start with minimum value between n and m and increment the i value by one until value is bigger than max of n and m

```js
function Sum() {
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
  var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = Math.min(n, m), max = Math.max(n, m); i <= max; i++){
    if(i%2==0) s += i;
  }
  
 alert(s);
}
```

```html
Enter first number:
<input type="text" id="n" />
<br/> Enter second number:
<input type="text" id="m" />
<br/>
<button onclick="Sum()">Sum</button>
```

Comment: You were faster than me ! The op want the sum of even number, so the condition is i%2 == 0; and not '!='

Answer (score 0):

Get the start and end values - then, iterate over them and increment the final sum - finally, alert the sum:

```js
function Sum() {
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
  var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
  var finalSum = 0;
  for (var i = n; i <= m; i++) {
    if (!(i % 2)) {
      finalSum += i;
    }
  }
  alert(finalSum);
}
```

```html
Enter first number:
<input type="text" id="n" />
<br/> Enter second number:
<input type="text" id="m" />
<br/>
<button onclick="Sum()">Sum</button>
```

Test this - entering `3` and `7`, the even numbers between them are `4` and `6`. `4 + 6 = 10`, so `10` is alerted.

Comment: you don't take care if n>m tho